# hide search box in iframe MapBox embedded map

Tags: mapbox

I successfully followed the MapBox iframe tutorial (https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/iframe/) to add a map in my website, now I need to hide the search box from the map, I suppose there is some additional parameter to add in the string but can't figure out how.
Thanks for the help.

[this is the map with the search box that I need to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS0xF.png)

Comment: Can you share your Iframe code that you used in your webSite?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the code

<iframe
src='https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11.html?&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYXZpb3BvcnRvbGFubyIsImEiOiJja212cmRrd2QwN3dzMnZuMXV2d25xbWsxIn0.x3y36v9arY9wmBOCZlCXUA#15/37.771/-122.436' width='100%' height='500px' title=''>
</iframe>

Answer (score 0):

there is no Parameter to hide or show map-control box in case of iframe , i suggest use javascript Api to access a lot of parameters to control your embeded map

> important : revoke your access token , because you should not public your  secret keys

```js
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYXZpb3BvcnRvbGFubyIsImEiOiJja212cmRrd2QwN3dzMnZuMXV2d25xbWsxIn0.x3y36v9arY9wmBOCZlCXUA#15/37.771/-122.436';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.2.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```